# Fade In/Out On Scroll

Tags: slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to get this series of slideshows to fade in/out on scroll.
Trying to get it to do gradual fade but am not getting anywhere with this.

https://thetulip.community/Shannon-Garden-Smith

```html
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".image 1").css({
    'opacity' : 0.5-(($(this).scrollTop())/20)
    });          
});
</script>
```

I tried this but to no avail!
My knowledge of Java is limited, so I'm not sure how to have each one fade in and out on scorll.
Any help would be beyond appreciated.

Thank you,
S

Comment: I am running it on Cargo Collective as well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community.

I'm not sure which library you're using for your slideshow presentation, but jQuery has built in methods to fade HTML elements in or out. You can view them here:

- https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Note that each method has an optional function to call once the animation is completed, which is called once per element match. One approach could be to call fadeOut() on click, and then call fadeIn() within the fadeOut method's complete function. For example:

```
var images = [
  "https://freight.cargo.site/w/750/i/0c4f83626e13ce4aa69fee4a84d02618c43afa3ff33d3c6bbd8fd6e265aa5538/01-03-downwrong.jpg",
  "https://freight.cargo.site/w/750/i/3aa2564a6c11b13ef5c44820c69b00563e89ddd572372d52d60b6a0bfd80d1bc/01-04-downwrong.jpg"
]

var i = 0;

$(function() {
    $('img').attr('src', images[i]);
});

$('img').click(function() { 

    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {

        i = i === images.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
        $('img').attr('src', images[i]);
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/matthewmeppiel/n28hg4qj/5/

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for getting back to me. I'm not sure to be honest, which library, but what I am looking to do is keep the slideshows functioning as they are but to have the first images fade in on the scroll. But as I scroll down the page, the slideshows will fade out as well, and if I scroll back up they fade back in.

Hopefully I am making sense. (?)

Comment: So it Is Jquery, I think I have to use .fadetoggle? I need to have the fade start at a pixel position on the scroll in order to activate that given command?